# Please check my segFault

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

I got the seg fault in here. I confused.
Please help me out. f1 and y are both pointer for struct node. 
I want to turn y's left to f1 right.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct node{
            int data;
              struct node* left;
              struct node* right; 
};
int main(){
    struct node* f1=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    struct node* y=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    f1->data=10;
    y=f1->right;
    f1->right=y->left;   //seg fault is in this line. 

    return 0;
}`
```

Comment: Read also [about casting of malloc result in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: Don't cast malloc: http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/19410

Comment: `f1->right` is not initialize. and `y` has been overwritten.(memory leak).

Answer (score 2):

`y=f1->right` sets `y` to uninitialised memory. `y->left` is now invalid. Try running this with Valgrind.